# How to popup a download with jquery from mvc4 webapi

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, rest, asp.net-web-api

I want to download file on client side from api
apicontroller:

```
 public HttpResponseMessage PostOfficeSupplies()
 {
    HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    result.Content = new StreamContent(File.OpenRead("D:\\Others\\Images\\file.png"));
    result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue     ("application/octet-stream");

    result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
    result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = "file.png";
    return result;    
}
```

what about the client side code(view) with jquery to popup a download for me?

my client side:

```
                 $.ajax(
                    {
                        url: 'api/MyAPI'
                    , type: "post"
                    , contentType: "application/octet-stream"
                    , data: ''
                    , success:
                    function (retData) {
                        $("body").append("<iframe src='" + retData + "' style='display: block;' ></iframe>");
                                        $("#sp123").text(retData);}

                    });
```

I just want to popup a download

Comment: From your wording it is not clear to me what jQuery has to do with any of this? In the end you're just linking to an action on a controller; how you do it isn't particularly relevant.

Comment: using jquery to start a download from HttpResponseMessage(server)     I updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure whether you would be able to show a download popup using an ajax call, but you can show a download confirmation window, by submitting a form

```
<form id="downloadForm" method="post" action="~/api/MyAPI">
 <!--use this if you want to pass any values !-->
 <!--  <input type="hidden" name="Param1" id="Param1HidenValue" /> !-->
</form>
```

and from the JavaScript call it like this

```
$('#downloadForm').submit();
```